# Setting Up Zend Framework on CentOS - Unsure where to place Zend folder

Tags: php, centos5, zend-framework

I have a CentOS server and am attempting to setup Zend Framework on it.  The command which php outputs

```
/usr/bin/php
```

and php -i | grep include_path outputs

```
include_path => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php=> .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php
```

So, I copied the Zend folder from the Framework donwload to both /usr/share/pear and /usr/share/php and also copied zf.sh and zf.php to /usr/bin/php.

When I execute zf show version, I receive

```
bash: zf: command not found
```

Can anyone suggest further steps to take to ensure installation of ZF?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the [remi repository](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en) and did a `yum update;yum install *Zend*`. Zend should be installed correct and on a new ZF version you can just do `yum update` when remi pushed it into their repository (they are relative quick).